# Packaging and installing python bindings with CMake

Tags: python, c++, cmake, swig, distutils

I have a C++ project that I have generated Python bindings for using SWIG. I am now trying to finish the CMake file for the project by adding an install operation. But whenever I finish the install and try to call my functions, I get an error stating `foo has no attribute bar()`.

It has to do with the fact that Python doesn't know where the `.so` file that the bindings rely on is. If both `foo.py` and `_foo.so` are in the same directory I can use the bindings perfectly. I am struggling with figuring out how I am supposed to "install" both the Python bindings and the `.so` they depend on, all in a portable manner.

Obviously I could just export the install path of the `.so` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but this seems like a hacky work around for what must have a proper solution.

My `CMakeLists.txt`. I have cut out the bits related to compiling of my C++ lib `RTK`:

```
# Project
##

# TODO this actually needs 3.3+
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(RTKLIB)

FIND_PACKAGE(SWIG REQUIRED)
INCLUDE(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs 3 REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})

find_program(PYTHON "python3" REQUIRED)
include(GNUInstallDirs)


# Variable declarations
##
# Define this directory 
set(RTKLIB_ROOT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

# Define the build dir
set(RTKLIB_BIN_DIR "${RTKLIB_ROOT}/build")

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${RTKLIB_ROOT}/cmake")

# Setup python vars
set(SETUP_PY_IN "${RTKLIB_ROOT}/setup.py.in")  # initial version of setup.py
set(SETUP_PY    "${RTKLIB_BIN_DIR}/setup.py")     # cmake generated setup.py
set(OUTPUT      "${RTKLIB_BIN_DIR}/python_timestamp") # Timestamp used as dep
set(RTKLIB_PY  "rtk_lib")  # name of the python lib


# Set the output dir for SWIG
set(CMAKE_SWIG_OUTDIR ${RTKLIB_BIN_DIR}/${RTKLIB_PY})


# Generate Python bindings
##
# SWIG Config
SET_PROPERTY(SOURCE include/rtk_lib.i PROPERTY CPLUSPLUS ON)
SWIG_ADD_MODULE(${RTKLIB_PY} python include/rtk_lib.i)           # Generate C-Python bindings
SWIG_LINK_LIBRARIES(${RTKLIB_PY} RTK ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})    # Link the bindings with python

# Generate the setup.py file
configure_file(${SETUP_PY_IN} ${SETUP_PY}) 

# Build command that depends on the SWIG output files and updates the timestamp
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${OUTPUT}
                COMMAND ${PYTHON} ${SETUP_PY} build
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${OUTPUT}
                DEPENDS ${RTKLIB_BIN_DIR}\${SWIG_MODULE_${RTKLIB_PY}_REAL_NAME})

# Custom target that depends on the timestamp file generated by the custom command
add_custom_target(ALL DEPENDS ${OUTPUT})

# Install the shared library
install(TARGETS ${SWIG_MODULE_${RTKLIB_PY}_REAL_NAME}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})

# Install to user's packages
install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND ${PYTHON} ${SETUP_PY} install --user)")
```

And here is my `setup.py.in` if its any help:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='rtk_lib',
        version='${PACKAGE_VERSION}',
        description="""Python bindings for rtk_lib, allowing for serial and
                and file interfaces with RTK messages.""",
        packages=['${RTKLIB_PY}'])
```

Quick Summary of the code: It generates wrapper classes for the C++ that are Python compatible, then it compiles and links the wrapper classes with the Python libs and the original RTK C++ library. After that you have a directory called `rtk_lib` which has both your wrapper classes and the `rtk_lib.py` module. Outside of this `rtk_lib` directory is the outputted `_rtk_lib.so` shared library that the `rtk_lib.py` relies on. So in order to get the bindings to work, I copy `_rtk_lib.so` in to that `rtk_lib` directory and call `python3`. Then I can import the lib and everything is great.

I try to install the shared lib, but even then I still get the same `rtk_lib has no attribute blablabla()`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an old question, but here goes anyway.

See this example [swig_examples_cpp](https://bitbucket.org/arrizza-public/swig_examples_cpp/src/master/) showing simple C++ functions wrapped by SWIG, using CMake and CLion to build it. The C version is [here](https://bitbucket.org/arrizza-public/swig_examples/src/master/)

Here's the full Python Cmake file:

```
project(python_example)

find_package(SWIG REQUIRED)
include(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

find_package(PythonLibs)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
set(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS "")

set_source_files_properties(../src/example.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)

swig_add_library(python_example
        TYPE MODULE
        LANGUAGE python
        OUTPUT_DIR ../../py_out   # move the .so to py_out
        OUTFILE_DIR .             # leave the .cpp in cmake-build-debug
        SOURCES ../src/example.i
        ../src/example.cpp ../src/example.h
        )

set_target_properties(python_example PROPERTIES
        LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ../../py_out  # must match dir in OUTPUT_DIR
        )
```

After building it, run python test.py to see it go. Note it's all in bash/Ubuntu, so MacOs should be ok, but windows may cause you some churn.

See the README for the full details.